# SQL Server - Average preceding Not Null rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I'm trying do a simple average of the previous two rows.  The complicated piece is if a row contains NULL in the score column, I want to do the average of the last 2 NON NULL rows.

Ordering by not null does not work as it puts the current row with the rest of the non null rows.  Similar, creating a separate non null row number created the same problem.  I assume I have to resolve through an outer join but just checking if anyone is aware of a simpler adjustment to the below code).

Example Data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
             (
                 Team varchar(1),
                 date date, 
                 Score int
             );

    INSERT INTO @tbl (Team, Date, Score)
    VALUES
    ('a', '2020/12/05', null),
    ('a', '2020/12/04', null),
    ('a', '2020/12/03', null),
    ('a', '2020/12/02', null),
    ('a', '2020/11/04', '2'),
    ('a', '2020/10/03', '4'),
    ('a', '2020/08/02', '6'),
    ('a', '2020/06/01', '8');

SELECT
    date, 
    avg(SCORE+0.0) OVER (partition by Team ORDER BY Date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS Average
FROM
    @tbl
ORDER BY 
    Date DESC
```

Output:

```
    +--------+------------+------------+
    |  Row   | Current    | Required   | 
    +--------+------------+------------+
    | 1      | NULL       |     3      |
    | 2      | NULL       |     3      |
    | 3      | 2          |     3      |
    | 4      | 3          |     3      |
    | 5      | 5          |     5      |
    | 6      | 7          |     7      |
    | 7      | 8          |     8      |
    | 8      | NULL       |     NULL   |
    +--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with your input and output. Please check your data and if any changes is required then update you question. I will be easy to check.

Comment: It just needed to be run as one query.  I've removed the gap between between the data and SELECT query.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery with a top clause:

```
SELECT
  date,
  (
    SELECT AVG(score+0.0)
    FROM
    (
      SELECT TOP(2) score
      FROM @tbl t2
      WHERE t2.date < t1.date
      AND t2.score IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY t2.date DESC
    ) two_previous
  ) as average
FROM @tbl t1
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ad91643b0fa21fe8a78b78ded1ce498

Comment: This is looking the best option.  I was hoping to avoid this as I will need to rewrite a lot of code but it looks like there is not an easy avearge the next 'x' non-null rows.

Comment: Yep, sorry, with `LAST_VALUE` you could get the last non null value, but there is no function to get you the penultimate one. I don't think there is anything built-in in SQL Server that would help here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MSSQL, but this **may** work.

You could try wrapping your table in a CTE prior to using the Window Functions, e.g.

```sql
WITH tbl_CTE (Team, Date, Score)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT *
    FROM @tbl
    WHERE Score IS NOT NULL  
)  
SELECT
    date, 
    avg(SCORE+0.0) OVER (partition by Team ORDER BY Date ASC ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS Average
FROM
    tbl_CTE
ORDER BY 
    Date DESC
;
```

Comment: It will not give the desire answer because it will return `NULL` for date `2020-06-01`

Comment: Thank you.  This is the sort of option I will probably have to go with.  The problem is I have hundreds of different averages and sums within the same SELECT statement so was trying to see ('hoping') there is a simple solution without having to rewrite all the code.